# grub2 chainload windows10 cdboot.efi failed

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub

I have 3 partitions on the usb sticks.
p1 is EFI partition, p2 is a grub boot partition, p3 is a fat32 partition contain content from windows10 installation dvd.
I can boot from p1 and enter grub menu. I can boot from p3 and enter windows10 installer.

However, when I try to chainload the windows cdboot.efi from grub it fails.

When dropped into the console `grub>`. I did:

```
set root="hd0,msdos3"
chainloader /efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
boot
```

it raised:

```
error: cannot load image
```

if I chainload the cdboot_noprompt.efi and then boot
It seems did not do anything at all.
What is wrong?

I did `set debug=all`. Then during the chainload cmd, it said

```
Kernel signature verification passed.
chainloader.c:1047: linuxefi_secure_validate: 1
...
```

I cannot see any useful info from `boot`. I said:

```
sectiion 8 ".reloc" at ....
...
Discarding section
relocate_coff(): reloc_base ...
booting via entry point
entry_point returned -9223372036854775791
```

Comment: Is there a /efi/boot/bootx64.efi or /efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi for you to load like an installation?

Comment: the content is from an installer image, so there is no bootmgfw.efi. The bootx64.efi is not for this yet.

Comment: not for this yet? what do you mean? I think it is the binary that get executed by the UEFI when you boot from p3.

Comment: @Wang Two things to try: (1) have part_msdos.mod and fat.mod on p1 and do `insmod part_msdos` `insmod fat` commands before the chainloader command, (2) try `chainloader (hd0,msdos3)/efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi` (and use cdboot_noprompt.efi instead). What does `ls (hd0,msdos3)/` give from the interactive Grub prompt?

Answer (score -2):

Make use of grub-mkconfig:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It will write your partitions properly.